# Is it possible to fetch the delegate of a solana NFT/Token?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js

I want to fetch the delegated account/delegate of a specific NFT. Is this possible in either the native web3 API or Metaplex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@solana/spl-token` npm package to do it easily:

```
import {getAccount} from '@solana/spl-token';

const connection = ...; // make your connection
const accountAddress = ...; // get your account address
const accountInfo = await getAccount(connection, accountAddress);
console.log(accountInfo.delegate);
```